# Flutter expand/collapse a container with dynamic height

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend

I'm trying to expand and collapse a container dynamically based on the data received. Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
       AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 550),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          constraints: !isExpanded
              ? BoxConstraints(
                  maxHeight: MyUtils.height(221),
                  minHeight: MyUtils.height(221))
              : BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: MyUtils.height(321),
                  maxHeight: MyUtils.height(1000)),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: containerColor,
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
          child: Column(children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 10, 8, 20),
              height: MyUtils.height(36),
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: containerColor3,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6))),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => expand(),
              child: Text(
                'Show',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
```

The function expand() is as simple as changing the bool of isExpanded. I managed to collapse/expand the Container, but the problem is that the Container expanded until maxHeight, I want to make the expanded height dynamic based on the items inside. So I tried to set only minHeight and hoping that maxHeight will follow the items, but I got an error because maxHeight is not set.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: just delete the height property in the container and the height will be flexible

Answer (score 0):

```
AlignedGridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  mainAxisSpacing: 4,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Tile(
      index: index,
      extent: (index % 7 + 1) * 30,
    );
  },
);
```

use this package [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Do this Hope this will be helpful:

```
  Table(children: [
    TableRow(children: [
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          
            child: Text('Widget'),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            
            child: Text('Widget'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
     
    ]),
  ]),
```

Comment: But how can I specify for the container to expand the height to display the rest of the content inside wrap?

Comment: using table widget you can do that , use tableColumn or tableRow

Answer (score 0):

By default, Column tries to be as much as possible. You can control this behavior by specifying **mainAxisSize** param.

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // ADD THIS LINE TO YOUR COLUMN
  children: [...]
)
```

I recommend that you read this article https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints